# Remove last digit from B_NBR

Tags: sql

Remove last digit from B_NBR. These all numbers are different. anybody have idea about some specifice trick.? B_NBR is 9 digit number so i want delete all 9th Digit number & show up as 8 digit number. 
For Example:- 123456789,987654321, 
I want =      12345678 , 98765432,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TSQL,

```
declare @B_NBR varchar(100)
set @B_NBR = '123456789,987654321'
select  SUBSTRING(@B_NBR, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @B_NBR) - 1),
        SUBSTRING(@B_NBR, CHARINDEX(',', @B_NBR) + 1, 8)
```

Comment: I appreciate all Helpfull answers , but i have B_NBR records arround 354234.. how can i change all in one time ?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply cast it as a varchar when returning the data, something like this should work

```
SELECT CAST(B_NBR AS NVARCHAR(8))
```